# How do I draw symbols above arrows in tikz?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I am using the following code to draw a commutative diagram and I want to draw the 
chi above the arrow but I don't know how

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}
    & I &\\
    0 \arrow[r]&M \arrow[r, "\psi"] \arrow[u, "\phi" near start] & N \arrow[lu, "\chi" near end]
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Is there a way to get the chi above the arrow from N to I?

Comment: Try `swap` option.

Comment: `\arrow[lu, "\chi" {near end,swap}]` as @CarLaTeX says. A prime also works `\arrow[lu,"\chi"' near end]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can swap the labels with a prime.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}
    & I &\\
    0 \arrow[r]&M \arrow[r, "\psi"] \arrow[u, "\phi" near start] & 
    N \arrow[lu,"\chi"' near end]
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a short cut of `swap`, as [suggested by @CarLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528591/how-do-i-draw-symbols-above-arrows-in-tikz#comment1336817_528591), which then leads to the arguably cleaner syntax:

```
\arrow[lu, "\chi" {near end,swap}]
```